# Networks and data flow - graph algorithms for propagating updates from nodes correctly

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, distributed-systems, network-flow

Suppose I have an acyclic directed graph of Nodes which subscribe to Events. When an Event callback is activated for some Node, the Node's internal update() method is called. Then, because the Node has updated(), it needs to call all of the Nodes it is pointing to and tell them to update() as well, and this process repeats recursively throughout the graph.

One snag is what I am calling the "incomplete update problem." Suppose A is updated, and it notifies B and C, which it points to. B updates and doesn't point to anything. C updates, however, and points to B, telling B to update *again*. The problem is that B has now updated twice: an initial "incomplete update" on an in-between state in which only A has been updated, and then the real update incorporated by updating the updated state from both A and C. It would thus be best if we first updated A, then C, then B.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a basic name for this general problem, or algorithms that solve this correctly, or literature on this?
2. Clearly one possible solution is to centralize everything and perform a topological sort of the graph. This would require some kind of centralized graph structure which has perfect knowledge of the call graph: Nodes have to register with the Graph such that it knows which update() callbacks will cause other update() callbacks to activate. However, this is quite a bit of overhead, and not always easy to do, particularly if Nodes have complex logic regarding how to react to their inputs updating in different ways.
3. One possible solution to *that* is to have the graph do a "worst-case" initial topological sort, in which all possible update()'s in the graph are hypothetically propagated. Then start with the first Node, and see which other Nodes the first one actually does attempt to update() and which one it doesn't. Then, with this information, we can prune the graph, and repeat. This seems like it will work.
4. However, it is quite a task to have to build this all out. Is there some clever *decentralized* algorithm which will do, which doesn't involve building this huge UpdatePropagationManager? The main issue is that node B needs some way to know how long to "wait" until it is sure all of its inputs which are going to update() have indeed done so, but B doesn't in general know about every other Node's logic regarding how updates will propagate.
5. I was thinking about perhaps some clever way in which Nodes could propagate messages of the form "I have chosen not to update(), so don't wait on me", so Nodes have some indication of when they are clear to update() themselves, but this could also be quite computationally expensive as the algorithm could largely consist of a lot of useless "I have chosen not to update()" messages flowing through the graph.

In general, this general situation feels to me as though it is some very general situation involving graphs, and I am curious if there is any literature on it.